# MongoDb aggregation framework push all values of a field to an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want an aggregation to transform an array of documents like this:

```
[
  {
    "key": "key1"
  },
  {
    "key": "key2"
  }
]
```

into an array of:

```
[
  "key1",
  "key2"
]
```

Thanks!

Comment: I tried this without success: https://mongoplayground.net/p/-r1BuZiLwxU

Comment: Try this : https://mongoplayground.net/p/xkpGlNi9MwE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue with your query:**

In your query when you're doing `{ $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$key" } }`, `$key` will get value of `key` field i.e; `key1` for 1st doc & `key2` for 2nd doc. But as `$replaceRoot` takes in an object and make that object as new doc (Root of the document) it's find a string value rather-than an object, which is why it's failing. Anyhow you need to use `$group` stage to do this which iterates on all docs *(Vs)* `$replaceRoot` stage will be executed on each doc individually.

Putting my comment as answer with added description : When you use aggregation you'll either get an empty array `[]` if not matching docs found/not docs exists ***Or*** else you'll get an arrays of objects/object `[{},{}] or [{}]` in the result. So you can't get an array of elements in the result like : `['key1','key2']`, as I said aggregation result array will have a doc in it, then it will be like `[{keys : ['key1','key2']}]`. You can get it by using below query :

**Query :**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  /** grouping all docs without any condition in `_id` & pushing all values to an array `keys` (name is just a choice), for unique values use `$addToSet` instead of `$push`. */
  {
    $group: { _id: "", keys: { $push: "$key" } } },
  {
    $project: { _id: 0, keys: 1 } // Optional stage, You need to remove `_id` from result as it's included by default
  }
])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lcgFheG3jpT)

**Ref :** [aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) operator

```
db.getCollection('collection_name').aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      key: {
        $push: "$key"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/NfLonicjkaZ